# JQuery GET Communication Ubuntu - Debian

Tags: jquery, ajax, linux, ubuntu, get

I am stuck with following situation:
Currently I have 2 virtual machines running (one with Ubuntu 14.10 and the other one with Debian Wheezy). Both are in the same local network and I am able to ping each other.

The idea is to have a WebUI running on Ubuntu which sends a HTTP get request to Debian - which should then provide a XML file for Ubuntu.

Unfortunately I am not able to use JQuery GET, as I will always get an error message (including "status 404").

At the moment my JS code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '192.168.178.43',  //ip debian
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        console.log("the response is", responseData);

    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        console.warn(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown);
        alert('JSONP failed - ' + textStatus);
        console.log("the response is", responseData);
    }

});
```

I keep tcpdump running on debian to check the network communication but nothing shows up.
Do you have any ideas what might be wrong or how to test the connection?

Thank you so much

Thomas

Comment: Are those ips visible from where you are displaying the page? you could try a wget from the command line.

Comment: i just checked: wget 192.168.178.43 returns a status 200 (at least this looks good)

Comment: But from where did you checked it up? I said that because when you have virtual machines sometimes it all gets confusing depending on where are you testing your things. Inside the virtual machine? From you hosting machine?

Comment: Don't you get any Security error on your debugging console (firebug, chrome etc.) ? maybe it's a cross domain security issue...

Comment: Sorry, for not being clear and thank you for your quick answers. I really appreciate it!
I tried the command from the terminal inside Ubuntu and I had a security issue ("Access to restricted URI denied"), but after changing a security setting inside Firefox, the error was gone.
Firebug outputs responseData, which is an array (including "status 404")